# Problema em centralizar imagens

Tags: html, css

Estou com alguns problemas em centralizar minhas imagens. Basicamente eu queria centralizar as minhas imagens no centro da minha página. Mas se por exemplo eu for para outro PC com outra resolução o meu site fica todo desformatado.

Queria saber se alguém me podia ajudar.

**css:**

```
}
.imagens1{
    position: absolute; 
    top: 220px; 
    left:310px; 
}

.imagens2{
    position: absolute; 
    top: 220px; 
    left: 550px; 
}

.imagens3{
    position: absolute; 
    top: 220px; 
    left: 790px; 
}

.imagens4{
    position: absolute; 
    top: 220px; 
    left: 1030px; 
}
```

**html:**

```
<center>
    <div class="w3-content w3-row">
    <div class="w3-col s4 imagens1">
        <br>
        <img class="mySlides1 w3-animate-fading" src="1a.jpg" height="312" width="237">
        <img class="mySlides1 w3-animate-fading" src="comida1.png" height="312" width="237">
        <img class="mySlides1 w3-animate-fading" src="cozinha1.jpg" height="312" width="237">       
    </div>
    <div class="w3-col s4 imagens2">
        <br>
        <img class="mySlides2 w3-animate-fading" src="1b.jpg" height="312" width="237">
        <img class="mySlides2 w3-animate-fading" src="comida2.png" height="312" width="237">
        <img class="mySlides2 w3-animate-fading" src="cozinha2.jpg" height="312" width="237">
    </div>
    <div class="w3-col s4 imagens3">
        <br>
        <img class="mySlides3 w3-animate-fading" src="1c.jpg" width="237px" height="312px">
        <img class="mySlides3 w3-animate-fading" src="comida3.png" width="237px" height="312px">
        <img class="mySlides3 w3-animate-fading" src="cozinha3.png" width="237px" height="312px">
    </div>
    <div class="w3-col s4 imagens4">
        <br>
        <img class="mySlides4 w3-animate-fading" src="1d.jpg" width="237px" height="312px" >
        <img class="mySlides4 w3-animate-fading" src="comida4.png" width="237px" height="312px">
        <img class="mySlides4 w3-animate-fading" src="cozinha4.jpg" width="237px" height="312px">
    </div>
</center>
```

Comment: As imagens ficam lado a lado?

Comment: sim, eles tão  como  eu  quero.  Mas n estão no centro  da página. tão  mais para a direita. e se eu for para outro pc com  uma resolução  diferente, o  meu  site fica todo desformatado. É basicamente isso.

Comment: Use Percentagens invés de pixeis pois assim ele nunca fica igual nos computadores todos

Comment: algumas dicas: primeiro, repare que o `width`e `height` de todas as imagens é o mesmo, então por que não remover do `html` e por numa única classe no `css`. Segundo, se você usar `position: absolute` e medidas fixas no posicionamento, não vai funcionar em qualquer resolução, deveria pensar em medias em `%`, mas tente usar `margin: 0 auto`  para centralizar na horizontal.

Answer (score 1):

```
<style type="text/css">

    .flex{

        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        width: 70%;
        margin: auto;

    }

    .center{

        justify-content: center;
        position: relative;
    }

    .img{width: calc(25% - 2px); height: 200px; background: tomato; border: 1px solid #bdbdbd;}

    .img:hover{background: #bdbdbd;}

    @media(max-width: 920px){

        .img{width: calc(50% - 2px); height: 200px; background: tomato; border: 1px solid #bdbdbd;} 

    }

    @media(max-width: 768px){

        .img{width: calc(100% - 2px); height: 200px; background: tomato; border: 1px solid #bdbdbd;}    

    }



</style>
```

```
<div class="flex center">

    <div class="img"></div>
    <div class="img"></div> 
    <div class="img"></div>
    <div class="img"></div>
    <div class="img"></div>
    <div class="img"></div>
    <div class="img"></div>
    <div class="img"></div> 

</div>
```

Basta adaptar as porcentegens que você precisa e colocar as tag's img dentro das div's com width 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Uma das muitas formas para vc centralizar uma imagem é utilizar margins e porcentagens que diferentemente de pixels, não depende da resolução da tela.

```css
.img {
  margin-left: 35%;
}
```

```html
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" class="img" alt="" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Para centrar as imagens Horizontalmente e Verticalmente pode fazer assim como neste [exemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/j9vcngxz/10/).

Com `transform: translate(-50%,-50%)` irá centrar tanto horizontalmente como verticalmente. O campo `left` e `top` teem de ser especificados.

Como você sabe o `width` e o `height` essa forma resulta bem

Comment: Embora este link possa responder à pergunta, é melhor incluir as partes essenciais da resposta aqui e fornecer o link para referência.  As respostas apenas por link podem ser invalidadas se a página com o link for alterada. - [Da Revisão](/review/low-quality-posts/159592)

Comment: Bem, eu expliquei que usei o `transform: translate(-50%,-50%) ` o que é basicamente a resposta